# how to remove default-jre java installation from Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, apt-get

I had no java (i.e. java -version said java no found or similar)

I installed it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

This results in installing java 1.6 - I need java 1.7

So the next probelem is how to uninstall it.

I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge -remove default-jre
```

Which seemed to work, but when I do:

```
java -version
```

I still java respond with 1.6 - i.e. id didnt uninstall java.

Ok, so I guess -remove does not remove the thing it installed. Is there a way to o this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java check the answer with bounty :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove default-jre
```

removes the package "default-jre". all tho you should ask in [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Just tried this.  it now says "package default-jre is not installed", but java still is working.

Comment: says "package default-jre is not installed", but java still is working

Comment: try this: `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre`

Comment: I am amazed apt-get does not have a way of listing installed packages.  I just tried your suggestion, and it proceded to do a lot of deleting stuff, and bizarrely, its also saying "the following extra packages will be installed: icedtea-70jre0jamvm...openjdk-7-jre-headless....

Comment: After the remove did pages of stuff, when I try java -version, I get back "java version 1.6.0_21" and it says openJDK runtime.  so unistalling again had no effect.

Comment: If I say sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre again, it now says not installed., but java still is.

Comment: reinstall default-jre and then:`sudo apt-get autoremove default-jre`

Comment: interestingly, if I do "ls -l /usr/lib/jvm" I see lots of weid and wonderful java versions already there.  E.g. java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  I wonder if the problem was that java was already on the box, but not correctly setup (so java command did not find java).  If this is the case, how do I switch to the 1.7 java?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default)

Comment: Just tried "sudo apt-get autoremove default-jre". Says pakcage default-jre is not installed, so not removed, but they says the following packages will be removed: icedtea-netx-common, thunderbird-globalmenu  Java -version still returns 1.6.0_13

Comment: Wow this worked: sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: Out of interest, how did you highlight the commands in your comments?

Comment: when you post a comment there is a yellow highlight under the text box that tells you how.

Answer (score 39):

**To completely remove jdk from your system, follow these below steps:**

1. Type `sudo apt-get autoremove default-jdk openjdk-` (Don't hit `Enter` right now).
2. Now press `tab` button for 2 or 3 times, you will get list of packages
   starting with `openjdk-`.
3. Look for name like `openjdk-11-jdk`. You need to get java version,
   here is 11.
4. Now complete your command to `sudo apt-get autoremove default-jdk
   openjdk-11-jdk`. (Change 11 to your java version)
5. And Hit `Enter` button.

Now you have done removing java from your system.

Comment: Thank You. Saved my day!

Comment: For me, I needed to remove openjdk-11-jre too so that I removed Java entirely from my system.

Answer (score 5):

Bary12's answer worked for me:

> sudo apt-get autoremove default-jre

Comment: How is this an answer? It's a comment.

Comment: worked for me, thats simplest answer

Answer (score 3):

To set the Java version interactively:

Log in as root or use sudo.

View the Java alternatives.

```
$ update-alternatives --config java
```

This command lists the Java installations and prompts to select from the choices.

Sample response

There are 4 programs which provide 'java'.

Selection Command

---

1 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

2 * /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-6/bin/java

3 /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-7/bin/java

4 /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8/bin/java

Select a Java version, at the prompt, type a number.

Press enter to keep the default[*], or type selection number:

Sample response

Using '/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-7/bin/java' to provide 'java'.

Verify the switch, check the Java version.

```
$ java -version
```

Sample response

openjdk version "1.7.0_65"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 7.6.0.1-linux64) (build 1.7.0_65-b17)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 7.6.0.1-linux64) (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

To set the Java version by path:

Log in as root or use sudo.

Specify the path to use when running Java.

```
$ update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/zulu8/bin/java
```

Comment: This actually helped me. doing `sudo apt insstall default-jre` was telling me I had the most recent version but I wasnt getting `openjdk version <version>` when doing `java -version`. I just changed the option in update-alternatives to the path containg the java version I wanted (Java 11 in my case)

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful for you.
firtstly,use this command to show all the jdk of installed.

```
dpkg -l | grep -i jdk
```

Secondly,use this command to uninstall the jdk.

```
sudo apt purge <package_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove Java 12 using this command--

```
sudo apt-get remove oracle-java12-installer
```

you can change the version by changing the 12 to the version present on your computer

then recheck by finding version -

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 1):

I Installed Default JDK like this

```
sudo apt install -y default-jdk
```

Removed like this

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jdk
```