# Can't remove java in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

> This post can be move to **Linux** or **Super User** blocks.

I want to install java 8 in my virtualbox ubuntu16.04, but whenever I check version using -version, it shows

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

To uninstall and reinstall java, I searched and find the following resources:

> [how to remove default-jre java installation from Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959615/how-to-remove-default-jre-java-installation-from-ubuntu)

However there is no java7 listed.

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
ii  oracle-java8-installer                      8u144-1~webupd8~0                            all          Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8
ii  oracle-java8-set-default                    8u144-1~webupd8~0                            all          Set Oracle JDK 8 as default Java
```

When I check Java version, it still shows java 1.7.0_05n. The same for javac.

```
>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_05
```

Any idea what's happening?

---

It turns out that the package I used was automatically changing $JAVA_HOME into a Java package in its directory.

Comment: That's not OpenJDK...that's Oracle Java.

Comment: and how to change the directory of `which java`?

Comment: Found out the answer myself. For `which java`, if we want to change it we need to add $JAVA_HOME to `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got Oracle Java installed, not OpenJDK.  If you want to uninstall it, you can do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove oracle-java7-*
```

In effect, you were telling apt to install something that was never installed on your machine.

Comment: I'm not deleting java8, I want to delete java7 on my ubuntu

Comment: @CharlesZha:  Fixed.  Given the way that Webupd8 runs their repositories, it's literally a one-character change.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove oracle-java7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java7
` I don't have it really

Comment: This presumes OP installed java using apt/dpkg, which isn't a safe assumption to make on any java installation.

Comment: @Braiam:  I would say it's safe for an Ubuntu user installing Java, given that the top few hits on Google indicate to use Webupd8's PPA.  To put the icing on the cake, **you can only get `oracle-java-7-installer` from that PPA.**

Comment: I've learned on all my years on AU, that unless you get apt-cache policy package, never trust the OP information.

Answer (score 1):

The thing I actually needed is to change the JAVA_HOME in the environment. For some reason `sudo update-alternatives --config java` doesn't really help choose the java version.

Here is what I did to solve the issue:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/jvm$ sudo nano /etc/environment
```

(In which we add JAVA_HOME = "/path/to/java", for me is `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"`)

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
$ source /etc/environment
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Thanks SharpLu and Makoto for the help.

Comment: All this accomplishes is that your Java installation now points to somewhere different.  While I don't know how you originally installed it, the answer to *un*install it still stands.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, thanks bro. I gave an up vote to your answer.